# Two structures with the same name, how do u choose one?

Tags: c++, vector

I have

```
int function(string n){

vector<int> n;


}
```

I want to call functions using the vector n, but..for some reason it keeps calling the string n functions..I thought it would call the closest dat

Comment: Just change that name...

Comment: Does your compiler actually let you compile that?  And, if so, what compiler are you using?

Comment: visual studios....this code is in complete obviously..this is only a part of it.

Comment: I can't change the name. The function's purpose is to define the name for the vector...

Comment: Visual C++ 2010 SP1 rejects the code:  `error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'n'`.  What do you mean "the function's purpose is to define the name of the vector"?  The name of the object is only relevant within the scope of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int function(string n){
    {
        vector<int> n;
        n.size(); //vector!
    }
    n.size(); //string!
}
```

Although really, just rename the variable.  Don't ever have variables with the same name in the same scope.  Ever.  People will hate you, and then there's all those nasty surprises in the afterlife.